# Webview unable to display url

Tags: android, webview

I have passed the URL link from one activity to another but when I try to launch it on webview, it says "Web page not available" but the URL is correct!

PS: the website is a working web

```
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    String link = intent.getStringExtra("item");
    Log.d(link,"retrieved from search"); //retrieve URL from details page

    web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    web.loadUrl(link);

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings ws = web.getSettings();

    ws.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.setInitialScale(39);
```

Comment: check internet connection or internet permission declare in manifest file

Comment: Hi, I have declared the permission in manifest file :(

Comment: as rajeshwaran sad: if the permission is set check your internet connection. open the mobile browser and check for example www.google.com . Dont forget, it is very important to place the permission on the correct place of your manifest. Maybe you can post the file for us.

Comment: I just did the checking for www.google.com and it works. I placed my permission just right below my other permissions, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: paste your link obtained from logcat

Comment: 09-25 08:52:09.536: DEBUG/www.accord-corp.com(413): retrieved from search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link should be something like this:

```
web.loadUrl("http://www.accord-corp.com");
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of Android (<11) i use

```
html = URLEncoder.encode(html).replaceAll("\\+"," ");
```

It's deprecated in newer versions so you could do a check on that like

```
int sdk_version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; 

if (sdk_version < 11) // < Android 3.0
{
html = URLEncoder.encode(html).replaceAll("\\+"," ");
}
```

I hope this will fix something for you.